# How to filter list in struts2?

Tags: struts2, filter

[image: table object]

I have list object above. The `All, A, B, C ...` link tag. When I click on one of them, the list below will be filtered. What is the idea for this?

Comment: How it would be filtered? Post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @RomanC : the records in list will be filtered by Location Name. I need the idea to code. Thanks!

Comment: @kidsoul If you find my idea is helpful, please don't hesitate to accept & upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have filter by the first letter, so filtering by some other value would be similar. All yo need to do is to build the  url of the link to include parameter with the link tag value. When you click that link then parameter would be populated to the action.

Then you change the list that contains the filtered rows and return to the page. This should be already implemented if you have done coding using the first letter parameter.

You can also pass this parameter further to initialize the SQL query parameter to return rows filtered by this parameter. In the query you can use `where` condition with the `like` clause to return all rows that have a column value similar to the parameter value.

If you filter the rows in such way then you should only initialize the list with returned records and you don't have to filter the list using Java. The action would return a result that will use updated list records on the view layer.